# Who put these roof beams over the chimney, I'd like to know?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, lateral-thinking, story

<sup>Before you read this, the credits: I came up with this puzzle entirely by myself, and the photo is mine.</sup>

---

I just bought a house last winter, and I was all ready to cozy up next to a warm fire in the fireplace, when that I noticed that, even though the house had fireplaces, the roof had no chimney!

Climbing up into the attic to take a look, I discovered that someone had built the roof beams *over top* of what remained of the tip of the chimney. So much for those romantic fireside evenings I was dreaming of.

[image: The roof beams over the chimney]

That wasn't the end of it, though. One day soon after, I found this message attached to the bottom of the mailbox:

> 5:↘
> 12:↗
> 19:↓ through →
> 33:→

My curiosity overcame my disappointment, so I decided to investigate into this; what I want to know is just *who* put the roof beams over top of the chimney? Specifically, since this is the first house I've owned, I want to know just their *first* name.

As I continued my investigation, I realized that the chimney wasn't the only odd thing about the construction of the roof...

Hint #1:

> Take a close look at the top left quadrant of the image, and you'll see what I mean.

Hint #2:

> The code is sharp... a well-known code.

Comment: Feel free to post an incomplete answer, if you wish! I've added a hint to the question, if anyone wants it. Don't be afraid to ask for more hints or more information :-)!

Comment: rot13(Znlor Fnagn, lbh znl unir chepunfrq n irel anhtugl crefba'f byq ubhfr. Onu!)

Comment: Don't spoil your puzzle by adding spoilers too quickly. Be patient!

Comment: @BmyGuest Sorry! No more hints for a while then... I'm just used to seeing users like Stiv solving the puzzles within the first 2 hours of their posting, and I'm also excited to see who will get it :-).

Answer (score 1):

I'll give it a go

> it looks like there are some letter written on the last right brick (the one on the right) on the forth row of bricks counting from the bottom up
>  [image] But I cannot make it out. Looks like an E and then a T or an L.
>  I mean here
>  [image]

The idea..

> Start from the top left quadrant and follow the beams according to the arrows. (see the white lines I drew perfectly with my awesome pinta skills) I took a leap of faith at the last arrow (horizontal) and tried on every row of bricks and zoomed in a lot.

Comment: Wow, now that's lateral thinking ;-)! This isn't the answer, but fortunately, rot13 gur nafjre vfa'g nf uvqqra nf gung: rirelguvat lbh arrq jvyy or va gur gbc yrsg dhnqenag. Vs lbh jnag nabgure (ovt) uvag, ybbx ng Erivfvba Frira va gur dhrfgvba'f rqvg uvfgbel.  Of course, you still get an upvote! I'm going to try to make my puzzles [less difficult](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6047/79067), so some of my future puzzles should be more clear. I'm still new to this puzzle-writing stuff!